# Laravel Group Query Result by Day on Month-Year (show all date if not exist date)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a table `exampleTable` :

```
+------------+--------+
| created_at | result |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-05-21 |      3 |
| 2021-05-21 |      4 |
| 2021-05-22 |      5 |
| 2021-05-23 |      6 |
| 2021-05-23 |      7 |
```

I want result:

```
+------------+--------+
| day        | sumAll |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-05-01 |      0 |
| 2021-05-02 |      0 |
| 2021-05-03 |      0 |
....
| 2021-05-21 |      7 |
| 2021-05-22 |      5 |
| 2021-05-23 |     13 |
....
| 2021-05-29 |      0 |
| 2021-05-30 |      0 |
| 2021-05-21 |      0 |
```

And this my query:

```
$results = ExampleTable::select(
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%M-%d') as day"),
    DB::raw('sum(result) as sumAll')
)
->whereMonth("created_at", '05')
->whereYear("created_at", '2021')
->groupBy('day')
->get();
```

But that not show if date not exist.
I want day value with date and result value set 0 if data not exist

Comment: You must generate dates list (calendar) then leftjoin your data to it and summarize finally. Generation method depends on precise MySQL version (or you may use static service table with numbers from 1 to 31).

Comment: Is `created_at` a text column?

Comment: how to using eqoluent?. no that is timestamp but i'm remove time in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new collection via `php artisan make:collection \\App\\Collections\\ExampleCollection`
2. Do the following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Collections;

use DatePeriod;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
 
class ExampleCollection extends Collection
{
    public function withDefaults()
    {
        $date = $this->sortBy('day')[0]->day->firstOfYear();
        $days = array_map(function($day) {
            return $day->format('Y-m-d');
        }, [...new DatePeriod("R11/{$date->toIso8601ZuluString()}/P1D")]); // e.g. 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z
        $collection = array_fill_keys(array_fill_keys($days, []));
        foreach($this as $item) {
            $collection[$item->day->format('Y-m-d')] = $item;
        }
        return collect($collection);
    }
}
```

3. Inside your `ExampleTable` model add this:

```php
    public function newCollection(array $models = [])
    {   
        return new ExampleCollection($models);
    }
```

4. Use it like this:

```php
$results = ExampleTable::select(
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%M-%d') as day"),
    DB::raw('sum(result) as sumAll')
)
->whereMonth("created_at", '05')
->whereYear("created_at", '2021')
->groupBy('day')
->get()
->withDefaults();
```

Comment: thanks, it's wonderful. I'm found error at function withDefault but not problem, I'm modification that.

Comment: Happy to help :) Where did you find the error? I'll fix my answer right away